# How to mock FileInputStream and other *Streams

Tags: java, junit, inputstream, mockito

I have class that gets GenericFile as input argument reads data and does some additional processing. I need to test it:

```
public class RealCardParser {

    public static final Logger l = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RealCardParser.class);

    @Handler
    public ArrayList<String> handle(GenericFile genericFile) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream((File) genericFile.getFile());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine = br.readLine();//skip header
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            l.info("handling in parser: {}", strLine);
            strings.add(strLine);
        }
        br.close();
        return strings;
    }
}
```

The issue is with new FileInputStream. I can mock GenericFile but it is useless cause FileInputStream checks if file exists. I changed my class so:

```
public class RealCardParser {

    public static final Logger l = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RealCardParser.class);

    protected BufferedReader getBufferedReader(GenericFile genericFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream((File) genericFile.getFile());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    }

    @Handler
    public ArrayList<String> handle(GenericFile genericFile) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader(genericFile);
        String strLine = br.readLine();//skip header
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            l.info("handling in parser: {}", strLine);
            strings.add(strLine);
        }
        br.close();
        return strings;
    }
}
```

So now I can override method getBufferedReader and test method handler:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RealCardParserTest {

    RealCardParser parser;

    @Mock
    GenericFile genericFile;

    @Mock
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    @Mock
    File file;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        parser = new RealCardParser() {
            @Override
            public BufferedReader getBufferedReader(GenericFile genericFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
                return bufferedReader;
            }
        };

        when(genericFile.getFile()).thenReturn(file);
        when(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn("header").thenReturn("1,2,3").thenReturn(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testParser() throws Exception {
        parser.handle(genericFile);
        //do some asserts
    }
}
```

Handler method now is covered with tests, but I still have uncovered method getBufferedReader that leads to cobertura problems.
How to test method getBufferedReader or maybe there is another solution of the problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but could I suggest that `makeBufferedReader` might be a better name for that method than `getBufferedReader`?  To most Java developers, names that start with `get` strongly suggest that you're just returning an existing property, rather than making something new.

Answer (score 4):

You can mock FileInputStream by using PowerMockRunner and PowerMockito. See the below code for mocking-

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({
        FileInputStream.class
})
public class A{

 @Test
        public void testFileInputStream ()
                    throws Exception
       {
           final FileInputStream fileInputStreamMock = PowerMockito.mock(FileInputStream.class);
           PowerMockito.whenNew(FileInputStream.class).withArguments(Matchers.anyString())
                               .thenReturn(fileInputStreamMock);
    //Call the actual method containing the new constructor of FileInputStream 

        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is a bad idea, but my first approach would have been creating an actual test-file rather than mocking the stream object.

One could argue that this would test the `GenericFile` class rather than the `getBufferedReader` method.

Maybe an acceptable way would be to return an actually existing test-file through the mocked `GenericFile` for testing the `getBufferedReader`?

Comment: I thought about it but it would not be unit-test anymore but kind of integration test

Comment: I do not see any ways around that, I am afraid. Maybe someone with more experience in writing tests can help here. Even if you got rid of the FileInputStream in your implementation as @Jens suggests, you would still have to test with "the real thing" at some point.

Comment: Internally created `java.io` objects can be mocked with PowerMock or JMockit, but the best solution here is what this answer suggests, to use an actual file. It would still be a unit test as long as `GenericFile` gets mocked (though even for that a real object could arguably be used). I see multiple quality issues in the tested class, however (like returning `ArrayList` and emitting pointless debug info, among others).

Answer (score 2):

I would first extract the creation of the Stream into a dependency. So your RealCardParser gets a StreamSource as a dependency.

Now you can take appart your problem:

1. for your current test provide a mock (or in this case I would prefer a fake) implementation returning a Stream constructed from a String.
2. Test the actual StreamSource with a real file, ensuring that it returns the correct content and what not.

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't the answer that you want.

The idea of unit testing is to make sure your logic is correct.  Unit tests catch bugs where incorrect logic has been written.  If a method contains no logic (that is, no branching, looping or exception handling), then it is uneconomical to unit test it.  By that, I mean that a unit test costs money - time to write it, and time to maintain it.  Most unit tests pay us back for that investment, either by finding bugs, or re-assuring us that there are no bugs in the domain of what is being tested.

But a unit test for your `getBufferedReader` method would not pay you back for our investment.  It has a finite cost, but zero benefit, because there is no actual logic that can go wrong.  Therefore, you should NOT write such a unit test.  If your Cobertura settings or your organisational standards require the existence of such a unit test, then those settings or standards are WRONG and should be changed.  Otherwise, your employer's money is being spent on something that has an infinite cost:benefit ratio.

I strongly recommend that your standards are changed so that you only write unit test for methods that contain branching, looping or exception handling.

Comment: Well I understood your post but our requirements are very simple and very logical: all classes (except primitive classes like domain-object or automatically generated objects) must be covered with tests greater than 80%. Because that class is small enough then avoiding testing method initBufferedReader leads to code coverage only 73%. Talking about that method initBufferedReader has no business logic that could be failed - I disagree. There could be thrown exception if file doesn't exists and there is type cast that also could throw exception.

Comment: Sure, you should definitely test the logic for handling those two exceptions that you mentioned.  But that logic is not _in_ your `getBufferedReader` method - it's in whatever method _calls_ `getBufferedReader`.  So the tests for that logic belong in the tests for whatever methods those are.  The only code coverage percentages that I believe in following are these -  you should have 100% coverage of the logic in your code and 0% coverage of the code that has no logic.  I think having a single percentage (whether it's 60% or 90%) as an organisational standard is a mistake.

Comment: I would upvote this answer if it answered the question. I really like what you had to say, but it doesn't really resolve the question asked (about mocking FileInputStream), which is why I can't upvote it. Good message otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

When you are having this question. You are probably not following [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) correctly. You should use InputStream whenever it's possible. If your write your FileInputStream adapter method like this:

```
class FileReader {
    public InputStream readAsStream() {
        return new FileInputStream("path/to/File.txt");
    }
}
```

Then you can mock the method to return ByteArrayInputStream alternatively. This is much easier to deal with, because you only need to pass a string to the stream instead of dealing with the specific FileInputStream implementation.

If you are using mockito to mock, the sample goes like this:

```
FileReader fd = mock(FileReader());
String fileContent = ...;
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent);
when(fd.readAsStream()).thenReturn(bais);
```

Comment: Or, the person who wrote the dependency you are using didn't.