# How to mock FileInputStream and FileOutputStrem consrtuctors on Android Unit Test?

Tags: java, android, mockito, powermockito, easymock

I have the Follow Scenario:

```
  public class A {
  public void TestIn() throws FileNotFoundException {

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("myFile");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out");
    doSomeThing();

  }
}
```

and I try to test it with the follow code base:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({
        FileInputStream.class
})
public class ATest {

    @Test
    public void testA() throws Exception {

        final FileInputStream fileInputStreamMock = PowerMockito.mock(FileInputStream.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(FileInputStream.class).withArguments(Matchers.anyString())
                .thenReturn(fileInputStreamMock);

        A a = new A();
        a.TestIn();

    }
}
```

the follow exception is throws:

```sh
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: myFile (The system cannot find the file specified)
    
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
```

PS: [How to mock FileInputStream and other *Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596075/how-to-mock-fileinputstream-and-other-streams) its doesn't works for me

Answer (score 0):

it was resolved just replace

```
@PrepareForTest({
        FileInputStream.class
})
```

instance of

```
@PrepareForTest({
        A.class
})
```

according to https://www.hellojava.com/a/41893.html