# Trying to mock java.io.DataInputStream.read

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock, datainputstream

My application has a piece that does the following:

```
public ResultObject myMethod(DataInputStream inputStream, int objectLength) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[objectLength];
        int bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
    ...
```

However, based on a piece ahead of this, the amount of data read out of the inputStream does not necessarily match the object length - sometimes it is less if the object is very large (>150 MB). I cannot change the upstream part of the application so instead, I loop through until I have read objectLength number of bytes.

```
            while (bytesRead < objectLength) {
                //keep looping and adding to my output
            }
```

I am trying to unit test the logic inside the conditional loop and am having a lot of trouble. The closest question I found was this one, although this hasn't got me across the finish line: [How to mock FileInputStream and other *Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596075/how-to-mock-fileinputstream-and-other-streams).

I don't want to create a real object that size so I was trying to simply mock the DataInputStream.read method and basically re-create the behavior with a smaller object. I was hoping I could return a real instance of the object with doReturn, but so far no dice.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DataInputStream.class)
public void MyTestClass {
@Test
public void myTestMethod() {
    int objectLength = 1024;
    String testString = BytesDecoderSpec.generateRandomString(objectLength);
    int testStringLength = testString.length();
    DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(testString.getBytes()));
    MyRealClass realObject = new MyRealClass();

    final DataInputStream mockStream = PowerMockito.mock(DataInputStream.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(DataInputStream.class).withArguments(any()).thenReturn(mockStream);

    PowerMockito.doReturn(stream.read(new byte[testStringLength/2])).doReturn(stream.read(testStringLength - testStringLength / 2)).when(mockStream).read(any());
    ResultObject result = realObject.myMethod(mockStream, testStringLength);
}
```

When I do this, I get a NullPointerException on myMethod > inputStream.read. I also tried using spy instead, but it didn't work either:

```
DataInputStream mockStream = PowerMockito.spy(stream);
PowerMockito.doReturn(mockStream.read(new byte[testStringLength/2])).doReturn(mockStream.read(testStringLength - testStringLength / 2)).when(mockStream).read(any());
```

Am I going about this all wrong? Any guidance you can provide is really appreciated - thank you!

Comment: You could step back a bit; `DataInputStream` is mockable using standard mocking (`Mockito.mock()`), so you don't have to use PowerMockito to mock the input to your method. `NullPointer`s are expected when working with mocks (because they return `null`s by default). If you share more details about the code-under-test, and where the NPE happens, we could find a way to wire the mock to handle the scenario correctly.

Comment: As @MickMnemonic says, PowerMockito should be a last resort